# Animated exclamation mark inside circle with HTML

Tags: jquery, html, svg

How to animate exclamation mark inside a circle in HTML using a jQuery or SVG or any other methods? The result should be like the one in the sweet alert: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/.

Comment: Read this http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/

Answer (score 0):

Here there's all the code you need: https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert.

Just take a look at the file `sweetalert-master\dev\sweetalert.scss` after the comment `// Success icon animation`. Indeed the animation is made with CSS3 and not with jQuery. For example, take a look at this code snippet: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_keyframes.